# Scala code generating a strange type error

Tags: scala, typing

```
  def foldLeft2[A,B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = as match {
    case Nil => z
    case x::xs => foldLeft2(xs, f(z, x))(f)
  }

  def foldSum2[Int](xs: List[Int]): Int = foldLeft2[Int, Int](xs, 0)((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)
```

The code above generates the two errors:

```
Error:(109, 67) type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: Int
  def foldSum2[Int](xs: List[Int]): Int = foldLeft2[Int, Int](xs, 0)((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)

Error:(109, 94) type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
  def foldSum2[Int](xs: List[Int]): Int = foldLeft2[Int, Int](xs, 0)((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)
```

I don't understand these two error messages. Especially given the fact that i never even specified the string type in the function signatures. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: You've used a type parameter called `Int`. Rename it to something less confusing, to `X`, say, and then look at your code again, you'll quickly recognize that it doesn't make any sense for arbitrary `X`. Very very very common mistake... Your code will probably work if you delete the type parameter `[Int]` altogether from `def foldSum2[Int]`. We have to invent a name for it. Why do "off-by-one" errors have a name, and this one doesn't?

Comment: The duplicate also explains why the strange `String`-related error messages are showing up.

Comment: This here also works: `def foldSum(xs: List[Int]): Int = foldLeft2(xs, 0)(_ + _)`. So, most explicit type arguments are unnecessary, and the very first `[Int]` is harmful, because it shadows the actual `Int` type by a similarly looking type parameter that is completely unbounded.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, it would be good if the compiler or IDE warned about this kind of shadowing, where the type parameter is also the name of an actual type.

Comment: @Tim A compiler warning would be a bit excessive for this. There are entirely valid use cases where one might want to shadow some of the types that are already in scope by some other type parameters (e.g. for defining local `FunctionK` instances). The problem essentially disappears as soon as one follows the convention that proper types are named `Int`, `String`, `List` etc., whereas type parameters are called `A, B, X, Y` etc. Then those two kinds of type names effectively end up in two disjoint namespaces.